# JavaFX ScrollPane scrollbar is disabled

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder, scrollpane

I have built a layout in SceneBuilder which has a ScrollPane (inside of a StackPane) containing a StackPane containing a Group (aligned to center-left) containing an ImageView. For some reason, whether I preview within SceneBuilder with Ctrl+P or run in my program, the horizontal scrollbar is disabled. The scrollbar does show that there is more to the right to be scrolled to, but I cannot scroll to it. It looks like this:

[image: Disabled scrollbar]

And here is the FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.Group?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>


<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <center>
      <StackPane prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <ScrollPane id="scoreScrollPane" fitToHeight="true" hbarPolicy="ALWAYS" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="0.0" vbarPolicy="NEVER">
               <content>
                  <StackPane alignment="CENTER_LEFT">
                     <children>
                        <Group id="scoreGroup" StackPane.alignment="CENTER_LEFT">
                           <children>
                              <ImageView id="scoreImage" fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="3000.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                                 <image>
                                    <Image url="@Untitled.png" />
                                 </image>
                              </ImageView>
                           </children>
                        </Group>
                     </children>
                  </StackPane>
               </content>
            </ScrollPane>
            <HBox id="toolbar" alignment="TOP_CENTER" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" spacing="8.0">
               <children>
                  <Button id="recordButton" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Record" />
                  <Button id="stopButton" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Stop" />
               </children>
               <effect>
                  <DropShadow />
               </effect>
            </HBox>
         </children>
      </StackPane>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

I've tried a horizontal scroll policy of both AS_NEEDED and ALWAYS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have numerous problems (most important is that the HBox with your controls covers your ScrollPane, intercepting that would otherwise go the ScrollPane):

1. Set `preserveRatio="false"` instead of `preserveRatio="true"` for your ImageView, otherwise the image may not grow to the fitWidth you provide (because it may hit the fitHeight limit first and not grow the width anymore).
2. Set `maxHeight="-Infinity"` on your HBox, (this will ensure that the maximum height of the HBox does not grow above the preferred height for the HBox, otherwise the HBox will intercept the mouse clicks intended for your ScrollPane).  Either this, or set `pickOnBounds="false"` for the HBox, so that the HBox does not intercept mouse clicks for the ScrollPane even though it overlays the ScrollPane.

*Note:* to debug layout sizes, sometimes it is useful to temporarily add a background or border to a region to see it's true size, for example `style="-fx-background-color: red;"`.

Also rather than placing your controls and image in a StackPane, which overlays content, maybe you might want to use a VBox instead, which instead lays things out vertically rather than on top of each other.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Indeed the HBox was covering the scroll bar.